# For installing bootstrap-sass gem do I remove *= require_self from application.scss or replace it with import '@require_self'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bootstrap-sass

I'm installing the `bootstrap-sass` gem and this line to do with application.scss confuses me.

'Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.'

Do I remove `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree .` and replace them with `import '@require_self'` and `import '@require_tree .'` or just remove them.

Also for any other imported files inside application.scss like

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require froala/froala_editor.min.css
```

should I change them to

```
 @import 'dataTables/jquery.dataTables'
 @import 'froala/froala_editor.min.css'
```

Just confused and would like a confirmation on what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using bootstrap-sass,remove everything from your `application.scss` and instead add the followings to it:

```
#"bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

If you wish to load additional scss/sass files then, you can **@import** them to `application.scss` 
If you wish to load css files then, you can ***= require** them like the followings:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require your_css_file
*/
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Ok so use `@import` on sass files and `*= require` on css files. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with the Bootstrap 4 Ruby Gem for Rails https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem. Its instruction also contains the phrase:

> Then, remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements from
>   the Sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.
>
> Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be
>   able to access the Bootstrap mixins and variables.

Here's a contradiction.

If I do what they tell me to - this means that I loose the opportunity to cancel bundling all my `(s)css`-files into a single `application.scss` (and a single `application.css` in the browser) while at the development stage. If I manually import all my scss-files inside `application.css` - that means that I inject each file's content into a bigger one and Sprockets has no longer control over such bundling - as I do it manually. And I don't like it - at the development stage as I can't clearly see which `css`-file this style came from.

So I chose another option - I left the `application.css` untouched, then I created a `bootstrap_code.scss` file (failed to name it `bootstrap.scss` as it confused Rails) with a `@import "bootstrap";` directive inside and finally I created some `z.scss` file for my own styles - just to make sure they would come up **AFTER** the same bootstrap styles.

Of course, my solution has such a drawback that my `scss`-files can not

> access the Bootstrap mixins and variables

(because Sprockets converts them into `css` giving them no chance to dive into Bootstrap `scss` first), but since I need just a plain `css` from Bootstrap that's OK for a moment.

Of course at the production stage I can return to the recommended approach described in the gem documentation ("remove all the *= require ...") should I really need the Bootstrap mixins and variables (something I usually do not need).